# Unable to extract JSON fields in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I'm trying to extract JSON fields from syslog inputs.

In `./etc/system/default/props.conf` I've added the following lines:

```
[mylogtype]
SEDCMD-StripHeader = s/^[^{]+//
INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = json
KV_MODE = none
pulldown_type = true
```

The `SEDCMD` works; the syslogs headers are removed.

[image]

But the JSON fields are not parsed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. Use the following configuration in props.conf

```
[yourlogtype]
SEDCMD-StripHeader = s/^[^{]+//
KV_MODE = json
pulldown_type = true
```